# How to Get Posts in Multiple Places in Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts, frontpage

I'm really newbie to wordpress theme development and I want to get recent 10 posts inside `front-page.php` and all posts inside the `index.php` (I have no idea if a better way is there) followed by pagination.

**Update :** I want to have a `home page` that shows 10 posts and a `articles page` that shows all posts.

Is this approach right? if it is, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research I found a solution to do that.

at first I created 2 pages called `home` and  `articles`, then I changed `Setting -> Reading` :

`Front Page` `->` `home`

and

`Posts Page` `->` `articles`.

then I put the following in the `index.php` as `articles` page :

```
<?php
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
    endwhile; endif;
?>
```

then inside of `front-page.php` :

```
<?php
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 10)); ?>

<?php if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : ?>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default ">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <img
                                        src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/image/placeholder.jpg"
                                        alt="">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 320); ?>...</p></div>
                            <div class="read-more">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->


    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

finally it works in the way exactly what I wanted.